# Getting undefined while accessing selected value of drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dropdown

In `lineItemIds`, I am getting the id's of all dropdowns. In the first iteration, I am getting the selected value of the first dropdown, but in remaining iterations, I am getting `undefined`. Here I am validating dynamically generated dropdowns:

```
var submitForApproval = function(event) {
    var lineItemIds = $('input[name="lineItemIds"]').val();
    var ok = true;
    var i;
    var individualId =lineItemIds.split(",");

    for(i = 0; i <= individualId.length; i++) {
        alert(individualId[i]);

        var value = $("select[id='"+individualId[i]+"'] option:selected").val();

        if (value == 'Select' ) {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!ok) {
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: please show the html part of this

Comment: You don't need `option:selected`. The value of a `select` is the same as the value of the selected option.

Comment: Do you have spaces around the `,` in `lineItemIds`? Use `.trim()` to remove whitespace at the ends.

Comment: Instead of `[id=xxx]` use `#xxx`.

Comment: Without the HTML, we can only assume that certain things might be happening. So please provide the HTML and make it a snippet, so it is easy for others to debug

Answer (score 0):

replace this line it will work.

```
var value = $("select[id='"+individualId[i]+"'] option:selected").val();
var value = $("#"+individualId[i]).val();
```

also check what is in your array using.

```
console.log(individualId[i]);
```